# Version control of MDF files

Tags: visual-studio, database-design, version-control

I'm working on a web app (it is in asp.net mvc framework beta in visual studio 2008) and want to version control it. How do I version control the database files (*.mdf, binary) in  the App_Data folder.

Is there a way to just store the tables-and-whatever definition of the database or do I really need to version control it's contents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Export the database structure as creation scripts, and potentially export some table (reference) data as insert scripts, then check those into source control.

Definitely do NOT attempt to put the database binaries (*.mdf) into source control.